# yii вместо 404 выдает 200

Tags: yii, http-status-code-404

Добрый день, кто -нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой. yii framework при переносе на страницу ошибки фактически отдает ответ 200, вместо 404?

Comment: не понял, вы о чем?

Comment: Да тут целая дискуссия была. Все уже удалили.